# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Error when building node application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to build my node application after bootstrapping my account and region, and I'm getting this error after executing `node run build` in terminal:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/.../cdk-eb-infra/run'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:955:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:803:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.8.0
```

Any idea what's causing the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/deploy-webapp-elb/module-three/). It should be `npm run build`.